# npm install module_name (locally)

Tags: node.js, npm

Installing a module by typing, say, `npm install ws` is supposed to install it locally for the project. And that I'll need to install it for each project separately.

I don't quite understand what it means.

For e.g. I have test files within `~/lessons/node_folder1`. While being in that directory in the terminal, I installed `ws` using `npm install ws`. Executed the files and it works fine.

Then I simply copied those files to `~/lessons/node_folder2` and executed the files from within this directory. Works fine.

This seems global enough for me, in that `ws` seems accessible from separate folders. So, please help me understand the difference between a local and a global installation.

Answer (score 0):

what npm install does is to download modules and place them to "your current directory"/node_modules/"module names"/

global install which is "-g" option in npm does not require copying local file to execute them at different directory.

try install express with -g option `npm install express -g` 
it will be installed to /usr/local/lib/node_modules(the case of mac) and you can use `express` from anywhere.

read here for more info
http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Comment: I ran the `npm install wm` when my current folder in my terminal was `~/lessons/node_folder1`. The wm module still got installed at `~/node_modules/wm` and not at `~/lessons/node_folder1/node_modules/wm`. Why ? (I'm using mac)

Comment: @KayaToast maybe it was already there. Clean everything and check again without global option.

Comment: nope. I find `ws` when I do `npm ls`, but I don't find `ws` when I do `npm ls -g`